# How to get the hash keys and values of a hash in perl mojo

Tags: perl, web, mojolicious

I try to figure out how to select explicit key and values of a hash.

```
my $hash = query('select id, name, required from table')->hashes
```

My output when I dump is:

```
var1 = bless ([
              {
               'name' => value,
               'id' => value,
               'required' => value
           }.....
])
```

What I want is to get the follow output:

```
var1 = bless ([
              {
               'required' => value
              }...
])
```

After that I want to compare if the index == index of another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You removed the class name from `bless`, but I guess it's [Mojo::Collection](http://p3rl.org/Mojo::Collection). Use it's `map` method to iterate over the elements:

```
my $required = $hash->map(sub { required => $_->{required} });
# Untested.
```

Also, using the name `$hash` for something that's a collection of hashes is confusing.

I don't understand your last sentence about the index. If you want to extract the `$index`-th element, you can use

```
my $hash = $required->to_array->[$index];
```

or to get directly the value

```
my $value = $required->to_array->[$index]{required};
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, i am total noob in perl. Well now i get all the values as requested, but how can i get the value of a single ? like $hash->[0] returns always the key.

Comment: It works so far, but like when i put an index in there, the indexes are not in a row like 1,2,3,4,5,,6 more like 12,16.21,23 why is that so ?

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: I fixed otherwise. Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Once you get a hash reference, from whatever means, you access the keys like this:

```perl
$hash->{required};  # etc.
```

See [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Arrow-Notation) for more information.  Also read perldsc and perlreftut.